# Saving model in pytorch and keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, pytorch

I have trained model with `keras` and saved in with the help of `pytorch`. Will it cause any problems in the future. As far as I know the only difference between them is **Keras** saves its model's weights as doubles while **PyTorch** saves its weights as floats.

Comment: Please provide us with the code you used for saving `keras` model as `pytorch` format. Besides that, they both have their own specific formatting when it comes to saving model weights and they're not interchangeable. But there're some ways to convert them to each other.

Comment: 1- please provide some code of what you are actually doing. 2- have you tried re-loading the model (preferably in someone else's computer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your model to double by doing

> model.double()

Note that after this, you will need your input to be ***DoubleTensor***.